# setInterval Speed Up | Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to gradually depreciate the interval in which the function inside a setinterval function is executed

Here's abstracted code for principle:

```
var speed = 100;
window.setInterval( speed-= 0.01 , speed);
```

Am I correct in believing the value for speed is taken once, on the first execution of setInterval and used, instead of being taken at every execution.
If so, how can I get around this? I verified this by setting the interval to 1000 and setting the "speed-=" to 999, and then printing the value for speed.
The value jumped from 1000 to 1 but then kept going down by 999, and even after the value became negative the functions inside setinterval were executed every 1 second.

Comment: Here is a example with increasing interval for better visualization https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/381/

Comment: Why did this question get down voted....

Comment: i thought set timeout executed something once with a delay??

Comment: nevermind i see the function is recursive

Answer (score 0):

An example of recursive call of setTimeout with changing interval.

```js
function go() {
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.innerHTML = speed.toFixed(2);
    document.body.appendChild(node);
    if (speed > 1) {
        setTimeout(go, speed);
    }
    speed *= 0.9;
}

var speed = 100;
go();
```